# Move-to-chat notification - can it be changed for a specific site?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

This has recently [come up on the Writing site](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/exactly-why-is-it-that-comments-are-not-for-extended-discussion/2142?noredirect=1#comment5617_2142): Can the language asking a user to move a discussion to chat be customized? My assumption is that this is a system-level setting and can't easily be changed, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You mean the wording of the comment? If so, change to what? Why?

Comment: @ShaWiz: According to the linked question, they want to add "or take it to meta" onto the end of the message.